# split a sorted into groups (From A to E, From F to J....) using java

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I have an alphabetically sorted arraylist which I have to split it into 5 sets Using Java
- set 1 containing list of words between A and E 
- set 2 containing list of words between F and J
- set 3 containing list of words between K and O 
- set 4 containing list of words between P and T 
- set 5 containing list of words between U and Z

Could any one let me know an efficient Method to do it. I am using Java 8.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: You can only collect a pipeline into one collection. Why not store into a Map<String, Set<String>> ?

Comment: Can you assume all words are capitalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with a sorted list, where all elements are *guaranteed* to start with a simple uppercase letter (i.e. A-Z), when the most *performance efficient* way is to using [`binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) and [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

Performance is *O(log n)* from the `binarySearch()`.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Actually", "Chalk", "Dramatic", "Fence", "Horrible", "Labored",
                                  "Resonant", "Six", "Slap", "Spark", "Tin", "Treatment");
int idxF = Collections.binarySearch(list, "F");
int idxK = Collections.binarySearch(list, "K");
int idxP = Collections.binarySearch(list, "P");
int idxU = Collections.binarySearch(list, "U");
if (idxF < 0) idxF = ~idxF;
if (idxK < 0) idxK = ~idxK;
if (idxP < 0) idxP = ~idxP;
if (idxU < 0) idxU = ~idxU;
List<String> listA_E = list.subList(0, idxF);
List<String> listF_J = list.subList(idxF, idxK);
List<String> listK_O = list.subList(idxK, idxP);
List<String> listP_T = list.subList(idxP, idxU);
List<String> listU_Z = list.subList(idxU, list.size());
System.out.println(listA_E);
System.out.println(listF_J);
System.out.println(listK_O);
System.out.println(listP_T);
System.out.println(listU_Z);
```

*Output*

```
[Actually, Chalk, Dramatic]
[Fence, Horrible]
[Labored]
[Resonant, Six, Slap, Spark, Tin, Treatment]
[]
```

---

If you start with an unsorted list, the most efficient way to do this is to create a `Map<Group, List<String>>` where `Group` is a unique value representing the group. It can be a simple `Character` for the first character of the group (`A`,`F`,`K`,`P`,`U`), or some other class, e.g. an `enum`.

Performance is *O(n log n)* from the [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)/[`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) building.

```
enum LetterGroup {
    A_E, F_J, K_O, P_T, U_Z;
    public static LetterGroup of(String s) {
        char ch = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'E') return A_E;
        if (ch >= 'F' && ch <= 'J') return F_J;
        if (ch >= 'K' && ch <= 'O') return K_O;
        if (ch >= 'P' && ch <= 'T') return P_T;
        if (ch >= 'U' && ch <= 'Z') return U_Z;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
    }
}
```

With an enum like that, you can do it using Java 8 Streams.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("dramatic","slap","chalk","fence","resonant","tin",
                                  "six","labored","spark","treatment","horrible","actually");
Map<LetterGroup, Set<String>> groups = list.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LetterGroup::of,
                                                                          TreeMap::new,
                                                                          Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
for (Entry<LetterGroup, Set<String>> entry : groups.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry);
```

*Output*

```
A_E=[actually, chalk, dramatic]
F_J=[fence, horrible]
K_O=[labored]
P_T=[resonant, six, slap, spark, tin, treatment]
```

Comment: @Joop Eggen: that trick might look clever at the first glance, but just implies that readers, not aware of the related twos-complement’s properties struggle to understand it (keep in mind that the Collection API documentation refers to `-index-1`). Now add that deeper knowledge that both variants produce identical bytecode, because there is no bytecode instruction for the `~` operator…

Comment: Btw, if you want to be clever at it, why not `if(idxF < 0) idxF ^= -1;`?

Comment: @Andreas: you can improve the performance slightly by only searching the remaining sublists in subsequent searches.

Comment: @Holger `^-1` to flip bits would indeed go a bit far. The rarely used `~` which is defined as taking the 1s complement fits here. Why that did not make it to the javadoc one can only guess. `-index-1` is the more incomprehensible expression. But the byte code is the same, and being too clever we may leave to the C programmers with `! ! x` and such.

Comment: @Holger If you want that kind of micro-optimization you should probably search for `K` or `P` first. Given the time it likely took to build the sorted list, I doubt that you'll notice such micro-optimization, so I'd suggest keeping it simple and clear, and not try any further *premature optimization*.

Comment: Since we don’t know how it came that the list is sorted, we can’t really say anything about its costs and it’s not useful to use that speculation to deny optimizations on this, actually unrelated operation. By the way, it sounds a bit schizophrenic to suggest binary searches without actually knowing the list size and then disregard further improvements as “premature optimization”. Especially when the suggested improvement doesn’t change the logic of the solution nor complicates the code in any way.

Comment: @Holger Adding calls to create extra sublists *does* change the logic, and extra steps *is* a complication. Same outcome and very minor complication, but don't say it's the same logic and doesn't complicate the code, because those are both incorrect statements.

Comment: Hmm, are you the same guy who edited his answer to replace `-index-1` with `~index`?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of qualifier function and enum e.g. (pseudocode):

```
enum Scope{AE, FJ, //...

  static Scope inScope(String s){
       return Arrays.asStream(Scope.values())
          .stream().filter(s -> isInScope(s)).findFirst().get();
  }
  abstract boolean isInScope(String word); 
}

Function<String, Scope> f = Scope::inScope;
// in code
listOfWords.stream().groupBy(f).values();
```

`Scope` enum defines groups by letter. In method `isInScope` you check is given word in  scope. Function `f` is just shortcut. Last line is operation of grouping words by scopes, that gives you `Map<Scope, List<String>>`, and extracting values.

General idea is that you have `groupBy` collector in standard API. They need classifier function. That function could be a bunch of if or, like in my example, enum.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution which also works for a non-sorted list is

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> m = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->Math.min((s.charAt(0)-'A'&~32)/5,4)));

// the keys range from 0 to 4, as can be shown with:
System.out.println("a-e: "+m.getOrDefault(0, Collections.emptyList()));
System.out.println("f-j: "+m.getOrDefault(1, Collections.emptyList()));
System.out.println("k-o: "+m.getOrDefault(2, Collections.emptyList()));
System.out.println("p-t: "+m.getOrDefault(3, Collections.emptyList()));
System.out.println("u-z: "+m.getOrDefault(4, Collections.emptyList()));
```

If you consider using the map instead of carrying five collections later-on, you may use pretty-print keys instead:

```
String[] key={"a-e", "f-j", "k-o", "p-t", "u-z" };
Map<String, List<String>> m = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->key[Math.min((s.charAt(0)-'A'&~32)/5,4)]));

for(String k:key) System.out.println(k+": "+m.getOrDefault(k, Collections.emptyList()));
```

Of course, this code also works for sorted lists, but it doesn’t utilize the sorted nature then. Exploiting the sorted nature for efficiency requires using binary search or similar techniques, as shown by [Andreas’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39561611/2711488). Of course, that’s a bit more complicated to code than a single `groupingBy` operation…